# Redirect multiple website to single domain in C#.net

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I need to Redirect multiple websites to single domain using URL rewrite or any other method.

We are having dashboard with one domain it's having lot of website as tiles. If I want to access any of the website means it should go through like subdirectory.

Say for example.

My dashboard is sample.test.com
All the websites should open like 
    sample.test.com/website1
    sample.test.com/website2
    sample.test.com/website3, etc... like this it should open. But here main problem is all other sub websites are having domain name in bindings. It's like website1.test.com

Expectation: website1.test.com -> sample.test.com/website1

Actual: website1.test.com

```
Request                                     Redirect to
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.domain.fr                          www.newdomain.com/fr/
Test.domain1.com.pk              www.newdomain.com/pk/
Sample.domain.co.th               www.newdomain.com/th/
www.xyzdomain.com               www.newdomain.com/xyz/
```

Please help me to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any reverse proxy e.g. `Nginx` or `Apache`?

Comment: @Twenty no I am not using any reverse proxy

Comment: Are you using asp.net core or why is this question tagged as c#/.net

Comment: @twenty yes I am using asp.net core and I have deployed in iis

Comment: Well then you should tag the question as such. Also take a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/)

Comment: @Twenty I have tried that above link it's just the single website URL rewrite I can't able to achieve it using above Method